# Loading USG-Transport models into FloPy from file

Tags: flopy

I have built a **MODFLOW USG-Transport model** with **FloPy** and I want to load the model from file.
I tried using:

```
Load model from nam file
mu = flopy.modflow.Modflow.load('%s.nam'%(model_name))
```

but I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\Emma\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\flopy\utils\util_array.py", line 2696, in load_txt
    num_items = nrow * ncol
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Is this because it is an unstructured model and does anyone have any advice on how to load my model?

cheers
Emma

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help you：

```py
mu = flopy.modflow.Modflow.load(
    'model_name', 
    model_ws='The absolute path of the model name file(.nam/.mfn))',
    version='mfusg',
    exe_name='The absolute path of the mfusg.exe'
)
```

I am new to flopy, hope it will be helpful.